# c++: Passing objects to functions

Tags: c++, templates, object

I was going through a code where I encountered some problem and was able to crack this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

class abc {
  public:
    abc(int x,int y) {
      cout << "x:" << x << endl;
      cout << "y:" << y << endl;
    }

    virtual ~abc() {}

    enum example {
      a = 1,
      b = 2,
      c = 3,
      d = 4
    };
};

template<typename T>
class xyz {
  public:
    void some_func(abc *a) {
      cout<<"some_func called"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {}
```

I want to call the function

```
some_func()
```

from `main()`. How should I do that. Can somebody help me with this??

Comment: This question is not about "passing objects to functions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an object of some specialization of the template class xyz and an object of the type abc.

For example

```
int main()
{
   abc a( 10, 20 );

   xyz<int> x;

   x.some_func( &a );
}
```